# Android studio showing this warning-libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

whenever I run emulator in my android studio it fails with the message-

"**libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile**"

could anyone help me to figure out this problem?